# Cakephp bake batch with admin

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I'm having problems baking controllers from the console WITH the admin. Whatever I do it just generates the simple actions, no admin_ version...

Tried:
cake bake controller all
cake bake controller all public admin
cake bake controller all admin

I think I'm missing something that is very obvious :)

Answer (score 3):

Just if anyone else is looking for this: For CakePHP 3.0-RC1 (and maybe the release version later) the command for baking admin controllers is:

```
bin\cake bake controller all --prefix admin
```

You can also substitude "all" with your controller name.
And to bake all corresponding views:

```
bin\cake bake view all --prefix admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually adding an 'admin' keyword will suffice.

```
cake bake controller <controllername> admin
cake bake all admin
```

What version of CakePHP are you using? And your post has all trials in a single line.. It would help if you can type in separate lines the commands you tried.

Comment: I'm using cakephp 1.3 and trying to run 
' cake bake controller all admin '
but it doesn't works.
How can I fix this?